# How many memory I could add for node 32 bit?

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory

After upgrade Angular to 12, I met out of memory issue when run ng command

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
[29616:09494E78]    39092 ms: Mark-sweep 998.1 (1044.6) -> 991.9 (1046.6) MB, 831.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.219, current mu = 0.019) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
[29616:09494E78]    40489 ms: Mark-sweep 1000.0 (1046.6) -> 994.2 (1048.6) MB, 1387.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.095, current mu = 0.008) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

The node version I'm using is v18.14.0 32 bit, I'm using 32 bit nodejs on 64 bit OS.

Search in google, I see lots of guys suggest to add parameter `--max_old_space_size=4096`, when I add it, another error report:

```
# Fatal javascript OOM in GC during deserialization
```

This issue does not exist on node 18.14.0 64 bit. How much memory size I can add on 32 bit node?

Comment: See my answer and the comments under it: If this does not yet match your environment, please add that information to your question (see [ask]). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory you can allocate in 32bit is OS *and system-* dependent. On Windows, it used to be a *theoretical max* of 2G, with practically being closer to 1.5G, and also depending on the time the system was running (due to fragmented memory). Looking at Jonathan's comment under this answer: In 32bit node in 64bit Windows, the value seems to be "*almost* 4GB", but please note that the keyword is "almost", it's definitely not the full 4GB - so leave some margin).

Also, 32bit systems tend to be quite old, and it's questionable if they have enough physical memory to allocate the maximum anyway.

You might want to figure out what your current setting is, and gradually increase it.

(Maybe unpopular opinion: ...Or just update to a 64bit system. It's 2023 - I didn't know that there was still 32bit Web Development being done. Old and forgotten servers: sure - but not new development)

Comment: Presumably, OP is using 32-bit node on 64-bit Windows. In 64-bit Windows, the limitation for 32-bit processes is (almost) 4GB.

Comment: Lots and lots of assumptions (for both of us...). Maybe I should have voted to close as "needs more details" rather than providing an "it depends" answer. The only one who knows for sure about their environment is OP.

Comment: thanks @OlafKock, yes, I'm using 32 bit nodejs on 64 bit windows. I have updated my question description.